# Unsupported driver [mongodb] Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.1 with MongoDB. I already installed

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Problem is I am getting this error when running my queries:

```
Unsupported driver [mongodb]
```

But I already have my drivers installed in my machine. I am using Windows 10 and WAMP. I can confirm it with php info:

[image]

I
 also check all my php.ini files which i already included my DLL's and looks fine. I have my drivers also.

My jessengers version is `v3.0.2`

Answer (score 8):

I think you are missing the line :
Add the service provider in config/app.php:

`Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,`

Refer the Documentation.

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

**Update:**
as a recent update after Laravel 10, the service provider shall be added like this

```
'providers' => [
   // ...
   MongoDB\Laravel\MongoDBServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: While a link to a potential solution is always welcome, an answer on Stack Overflow should always contain the main parts/points of the solution in the answer body itself. Merely a link to a solution with no further commentary is not considered an acceptable answer. See [ask] on how to formulate a proper answer.

Comment: @Magisch - you are correct. i will follow this. and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run this :

composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*

Comment: Could you explain how this would solve the question?

Comment: after installing jenssegers package

Comment: Posted 2 answers to a question, reason?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mongodb drivers in php:

- The legacy one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php
- The recommended one: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

[laravel-mongodb Readme](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) reads:

> **WARNING:** The old mongo PHP driver is not supported anymore in versions >= 3.0

Laravel 5.1 can be used with either jenssegers/mongodb v2.2 or jenssegers/mongodb v3.0. The former requires legacy driver, the later requires new driver.

Check which version of jenssegers/mongodb you are using, and make it agree with php mongodb driver.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion, so right now I am using the legacy driver? Also in link you gave me, http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php seems I can only see the class files, where can I find the DLL Extension file?

Comment: Why? The driver on the image is the new one.  What you need to do is to confirm which version of `jenssegers/mongodb` you are using. It is in `composer.lock`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I see the composer.lock it says v3.0.2 for my jessengers.mongodb

Comment: It should be ok then. I would suggest to add it to the question, to make it clear the versions of library and driver are compatible.

Comment: Yeah. I believe my settings is ok but then not working. Thanks though. What do you mean to add it in the question?

Comment: I believe it is related to how you register the jenssegers libs in laravel. There are 2 options in the readme depending on whether you use it with lumen or without.

Answer (score 1):

composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*

install jenssegers package by above command

then

composer update

you need to make database related changes in .env file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=mongodb
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and in config/database.php file :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb')

'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE','mongodb'),
        'username' => env(''),
        'password' => env(''),
    ],
```

modify above parameter as per your appropriate credentials.

Also in config/app.php

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lumen, make sure you are adding the service provider before $app->withEloquent();

Like this
$app->register(Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class);

$app->withEloquent();