# Unsupported driver [mongodb] : Laravel 7 & PHP 7.4

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-7, php-7.4

I am using Laravel 7 with MongoDB. I already installed mongo using

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

The package used is:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

This is the error i get when running migration or queries:

`Unsupported driver [mongodb]`

This is the response i get when accessing php.info file

Mongodb extension detail of php 7.4 [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUu99.png)

I've followed the solution provided in the question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688621/unsupported-driver-mongodb-laravel) and also the followed the official php documentation [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php).

I need to solve the issue that is occurring and should be able to connect to the mongodb using the laravel and ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are loaded from the appropriate files in the config/...php directory. You need to check that you have the settings for Mongo in the required section. If everything is written that you need to run

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

These commands will clear the cached configurations and the new driver should work.